# Show progress dialog while build big ui

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progress-bar

i know this is a common question.. i read this site and many tutorial many many times but no chance to do work.

well the code is this:

```
public class mostraRisultatiActivity extends Activity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mostra_risultati);

    int cnt = 0;
    final TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabellaRisultati);

    for (Esame e : Db.risposteDate){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        TextView lbl1 = new TextView(this);
        TextView lbl2 = new TextView(this);
        TextView lbl3 = new TextView(this);
        tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        lbl1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        lbl3.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        lbl1.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        lbl2.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);
        lbl3.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.RED);

        lbl1.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );
        lbl2.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 7 ) );
        lbl3.setLayoutParams( new TableRow.LayoutParams( 0, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1 ) );

        lbl1.setText(e.getDomandaNum()+"");
        lbl2.setText(Html.fromHtml(e.getTesto()+"<br />"));
        lbl3.setText(e.getRispostaData());

        tr.addView(lbl1);
        tr.addView(lbl2);
        tr.addView(lbl3);
        tl.addView(tr);
        if (e.getRispostaData() != null && e.getRispostaData().equals(e.getRispostaReale())){
            cnt++;
            lbl1.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
            lbl2.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
            lbl3.setTextColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
    double percentualeSucceso = (cnt*100)/Db.risposteDate.size();

    final TextView risposteTotTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.risultatiTot);
    final TextView riassuntorisTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.risRiassunto);
    final TextView esitoTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.esito);

    risposteTotTV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>TOT</big></b>" +  "<br />" + 
            Db.risposteDate.size()));
    riassuntorisTV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>Risposte corrette: </b>" +cnt+  "<br />" + 
            "Percentuale: "+percentualeSucceso+"%"));
    if (percentualeSucceso >= 90) {
        esitoTV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>Esito</big></b>  <br />" + 
                                      "<small>PROMOSSO</small>"));
    } else {
        esitoTV.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>Esito</big></b>  <br />" + 
                                      "<small>BOCCIATO</small>"));
    }

}
```

}

i want a progress bar while load the ui (in particulary the for loop)

i tried with a thread: all work but no progress show until the ui is loaded (useless)
i tried with asyncTask and i have always exception crash.

any idea?

Comment: What exception are you getting when you try the AsyncTask?

Comment: now don't remember, i deleted all for frustration. but was many things and the first was an error in the do_background() (where all my code was)

Comment: instead of trying to build a potentially long table with lots of rows and views in your onCreate, why not use a ListView and draw the [visible] rows on demand?  You should find that this performs fast and eliminates the need for a ProgressDialog

Comment: you say that a ListView have better performance that TableLayout? i never used ListView but i give a try

Comment: ListView is definitely the way to go if your table has more rows than are visible (without scrolling).  It will take some research to learn how they work, but will be well worth it.

Comment: well after many hours to understand how do a custom adapter i finally did it.. it is very fast and real good.. ty for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've only tested this solution with a very basic `Button`, but it worked, so here goes:

You can do the creation and setup of the `Views` using an `AsyncTask`. I tried with a button, and any calls that modify/create a `View` work without problem in an AsyncTask, until you add the view to the layout. Once added, any modifications *must* be done on the UI thread. So all your setup will happen in `doInBackground()`, and all the `addView()` calls will be in `onPostExecute()`. After `onPostExecute()`, and more changes to the View will have to be done in an AsyncTask.

Comment: tr.addView(lbl1);
    tr.addView(lbl2);
    tr.addView(lbl3);
    tl.addView(tr);

these go on onPostExecute? <br/>or only tl.addView(tr);?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't! to see the progress of the ProgressDialog it has to run on the UI thread. And creating your UI is already running on the UI thread that's why your progress dialog appears unresponsive. Also you can't use AsyncTask to create UI, you will always get "Called from wrong thread" exception. Wich means that you have to build your UI on the UI thread.

What I usually do is have a splash screen while the UI is loading and I remove it when everything else is ready

Comment: so? what is the best possible strategy to do this?